# Why can we avoid specifying the type in a lambda capture?

Tags: c++, lambda

Why is the variable 'n' in 2nd usage of `std::generate` and within lambda capture not preceded with it's data type in below code?
I thought it's important to specify the datatype of all identifiers we use in a c++ code.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
 
int f()
{ 
    static int i;
    return ++i;
}
 
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(5);
    auto print = [&] {
        for (std::cout << "v: "; auto iv: v)
            std::cout << iv << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    };
 
    std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), f);
    print();
 
    // Initialize with default values 0,1,2,3,4 from a lambda function
    // Equivalent to std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
    std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [n = 0] () mutable { return n++; });
    print();
}
```

Comment: `auto n = 0;` is a thing... now imagine you have a place where only `auto` is allowed

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica : Can you elaborate please?

Comment: how about `auto print = ...` do you understand why you need not explicitly specify the type of `print` ? or `auto iv : v`, whats the type of `iv` ?

Comment: not all type deduction requires the keyword `auto`. Consider `template <typename T> foo(T t) {}; foo(1);` as just another case where there is no `auto` but a type is deduced

Comment: please provide proper reference when you take code from somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

> A capture with an initializer acts as if it declares and explicitly captures a variable declared with type auto, whose declarative region is the body of the lambda expression (that is, it is not in scope within its initializer), [...]

Lambdas used the opportunity of a syntax that was anyhow fresh and new to get some things right and allow a nice and terse syntax. For example lambdas `operator()` is `const` and you need to opt-out via `mutable` instead of the default non-const of member functions.

No `auto` in this place does not create any issues or ambiguities. The example from cppreference:

> ```
> int x = 4;
> auto y = [&r = x, x = x + 1]()->int
>     {
>         r += 2;
>         return x * x;
>     }(); // updates ::x to 6 and initializes y to 25.
> ```

From the lambda syntax it is clear that `&r` is a by reference capture initialized by `x` and `x` is a by value capture initialized by `x + 1`. The types can be deduced from the initializers. There would be no gain in requiring to add `auto`.

---

> In my experience n could have been just declared inside the lambda body with auto or int as datatype. Isnt it?

Yes, but then it would need to be `static`. This produces the same output in your example:

```
std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [] () mutable { 
    static int n = 0;
    return n++; });
```

However, the capture can be considered cleaner than the function local static.

Comment: My confusion arose from the fact that i am used to using auto for type deduction and didn't knew that in lambda capture even auto can be avoided. In the shared code the variable n was completely new. In my experience n could have been just declared inside the lambda body with auto or int as datatype. Isnt it? OR having it within lambda capture makes any additional difference like retaining the value across multiple runs of lambda?

Comment: @Test see  update

Answer (score 2):

> Why is the variable 'n' in 2nd usage of std::generate and within lambda capture not preceded with it's data type in below code?

It's not preceded with a data type, because the grammar of C++ says that it doesn't need to - nor even allowed to - be preceded by a type name.

A type name isn't needed because the type is deduced from the type of the initialiser expression.

Comment: Then why can't we do n = 0 inside main without using auto? Is there any rule within lambda capture to avoid auto?

Comment: @Test Because the grammar of C++ says that you cannot do so. It cannot be allowed because that would conflict with the syntax of assignment expression.

Comment: So you are saying we can avoid auto inside lambda capture. I know what auto is . my question was why auto is missing in the code i shared. And if i use auto there then it errors out

Comment: @Test it seems like you try to see a commonality between two different things. There are dedicated rules for lambda syntax.

Comment: @Test It just sounds like you expect object declarations in lambda captures to be consistent with other cases of object declarations. This seems like a reasonable expectation, but the answer is simply that it is not consistent.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number My confusion arose from the fact that i am used to using auto for type deduction and didn't knew that in lambda capture even auto can be avoided. In the shared code the variable n was completely new. In my experience n could have been just declared inside the lambda body with auto or int as datatype. Isnt it? OR having it within lambda capture makes any additional difference like retaining the value across multiple runs of lambda?

Comment: @Test `like retaining the value across multiple runs of lambda?` That's what all lambda captures do. They are analogous to member variables of a class which also retain their value across multiple runs of member functions.

Comment: @Test try to call the lambda several times. `n` does retain the (incremented) value between calls. Actually thats the whole purpose of the lambda in your example ;)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number : wondering when c++ standard will introduce n = 1 even within main. If n isn't referenced before then consider as declaration with auto deduction and treat as assignment if referenced earlier.

Comment: @Test surely this will never happen. For one `int n = 1;` is initialization but `n = 1;` is assignment, they are very different. Moreover, consider this example which is completely valid, but will break when your suggestion would come true: https://godbolt.org/z/MYPTvhPKM. Neither of the two is an issue in a lambda capture list

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number : why auto deduction failed here? Clearly it could deduce that it's int reference
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // Write C++ code here
    auto f = [&n = 0](){
        std::cout << "\n N = " << n;
    };
    
    f();

    return 0;
}

Comment: @Test please open a quesiton if you want to ask a question. Code in comments isnt readable. Anyhow this fails for the same reason as `void foo(int&); foo(0);` fails. Why do you want to get a reference to `0` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number : makes sense. Thanks for clarification.